# beamer animated frame: variable reset

Tags: beamer, animations

I am trying to improve the `pdfpcnotes` package, that extracts notes in `beamer` into an external file for `pdfpc`. The main idea is that we have a counter (`\lastframenumber`), that checks if we stepped to the next frame and when this happens it does things once. My problem is, that somehow in this setup, if we are in an animated frame (i.e. `beamer` generates multiple pages for a single frame) `\lastframenumber` gets reset to the previous frame for each step of the animation, thus instead of doing things once, it happens for each animation step, which is an unwanted situation, but I don't understand why this is happening. Any ideas? Here's the code that doesn't work. The `pnote` command would be used inside the frame.

```
\def\lastframenumber{0}
    \newcommand<>{\pnote}[2][]{%
        \show\lastframenumber
        \ifdim\theframenumber pt >\lastframenumber pt
            \edef\lastframenumber{\theframenumber}
        \fi
```

Comment: I guess you are talking about overlay specification but not animate. If you want to export the header only when there is a new frame, you should use something like `\only<1>`. Or, more directly, hack `\frametitle` and `\framesubtitle`

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is the overlay I'm talking about. But my issue is not with the overlay itself. My issue probably just plain LaTeX: when the `\ifdim` clause fires `\lastframenumber` is set (at least that is what I'm trying to achieve) to the *value* of `\theframenumber` or the actual frame, to be more specific. The initial problem with this (why `\let` doesn't work is), is that `\theframenumber` is `\@arabic\c@framenumber`, the other one being that as done above `\lastframenumber` gets changed outside the `\ifdim \fi` thus triggering it again and again.

Comment: I am away from my computer so l am not sure... But did you try `\global`?

Comment: Cool, `\global` did the trick! It seems I have no idea about scope in LaTeX :)

Comment: Would you care writing that up as an answer so or you're not out hunting points?:D

Comment: Actually you can answer your own question:) I do not know `pdfpcnotes` and its application very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solutions is basically due to Symbol 1: in the original setup `\lastframenumber` only 'lived' for each call to `\pnote`. It seems that for a frame with overlay, that for each page generated the whole frame is read again, calling `\pnote` for each page, thus triggering the `\ifdim` for every page of the frame. Prepending `\global` to the definitions keeps the variable 'alive' outside of the command call thus making it actually keep the last frame number:

```
\global\def\lastframenumber{0}
\newcommand<>{\pnote}[2][]{%
    \ifdim\theframenumber pt >\lastframenumber pt
        \global\edef\lastframenumber{\theframenumber}
    \fi
```